# Unity how to change the default position of the Scroll Rect content in elastic movement type from center to the top edge

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I have a problem with default position of my Scroll Rect content. My content have dynamicly adjusted size and from time to time it is smaller than my Scroll Rect Panel. When the content is smaller than the Rect Panel it ends like that:

(Vertical scroll)

Green - Panel with Scroll Rect component

Red - Content of the Scroll Rect component

[image]

Is it any possibility to change the default position of the content to be on the upper edge of the Panel with Scroll Rect?

Scroll Panel inspector:

[image]

Content inspector:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly undersand what You trying to achive, then try next actions:

1. In Hierarchy view: make your Content object a child of a Scroll Panel object.
2. In Inspector view of Content object > Rect Transform:
   2.1) set Your Anchor point to the top-middle.(for change click on icon with cross, in the top-left corner of Inspector and choose corresponding icon from opened menu).
   2.2) You also may want to set yor Pivot Y to value of 1 - in such case Pos Y value will set the distance between Anchor point and top edge of Your Content object, instead of distance between Anchor point and center of Content object. It can make a difference if Y-size of Content would change in futer.